# How to horizontally align controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, alignment

I'm trying to align below controls horizontally by keeping the label and the combobox on the left and both buttons on the right. I've tried different approaches using StackPanel but nothing gives me the desired output. Appreciate if you guys could point out what am I doing wrong here?

> Current Layout

[image]

> XAML source

```
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,2" >

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label Content="Age Bucket" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="100" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedAgeBucket}"
              DisplayMemberPath="DisplayMember" SelectedValuePath="ValueMember"
              ItemsSource="{Binding AgeBuckets}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>                        
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,2">
                    <Button   Click="Button_Click_1" Content="Export" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Click="Button_Click_2" Content="Print" Margin="5,0" />
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>

            <telerik:RadDataPager x:Name="radDataPager" Source="{Binding Items, ElementName=grdDetails}" PageSize="100" />

        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Use a DockPanel instead of StackPanel.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your suggestion, will try out DockPanel right away.

Comment: StackPanel pretends that it has infinite width (if its orientation is horizontal), so right-aligning its children doesn't really make sense. DockPanel is a better choice choice here, but a Grid would also work.